# May God damn the guilty person

Tags: phrase-request, translation

In my mother language, when someone is going to curse or damn someone who's been the origin of a bad social disaster or someone who has caused a big catastrophe in a family and does not know who was the guilty person, says:

> - God damn the **cause**.

Where "cause" is the guilty person who's been in charge.
This is a direct translation from my language.

**My questions:**

1. Is there such a comment in English at all in such a scenario?
2. If there is, then does my sentence work? If not, please let me know, how should I indicate such a concept?

Comment: Instead of **cause** you could say **the guilty party**.

Comment: Good job; thank you very much @TRomano. Please make your comment an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: There is no real equivalent in English. While 'the guilty party' technically fits, "God damn the guilty party!" doesn't sound natural; something along the lines of "I don't know who did this, but God damn them anyway!" though a bit long-winded, sounds to me more like something someone might actually say. (I'm a native Br-Eng speaker)

Comment: @TRomano do you as an AmE native speaker confirm what PeterG mentioned in your language too?

Comment: A shorter form of Peter's construction would be "God damn whoever did this!"

Comment: Well, the "cause" is a legalism of sorts, and so "the guilty party", which is  idiomatic, seemed to fit well.  "whoever did this" is also idiomatic, as is *Whoever did this, may they rot in hell*. It depends on how much emotion you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exclamation

> God damn the cause!

is understandable, however one would usually say

> Damn *whoever* caused this!
>   Damn *whatever* caused this!

or

> Curse *whoever* did this!
>   Curse *whatever* did this!

One needs to be careful when invoking God, since some people may find "God damn" as offensive as whatever happened.

Comment: *Goddamn* in particular is somewhat strong profanity in many if not all places in the U.S.  You could say "May God damn X" to prevent it from sounding like a curse word but it could make you sound like an angry preacher.